# How to make custom urls having the same controller method in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url-routing

I have these classes.

```
Secion Repository
Section Application
Section Controller
Group Repository
Group Application
Group Controller
Class Repository
Class Application
Class Controller
```

and all of my controllers have a view named `Show`
And these structure of entities.
[image]

Now the question is this:
I want when I go to the `Class` controller I see

```
Class/Show/class's group's section name/class's group name/class's name
```

instead of

```
Class/Show/1
```

or when I go to the Group controller I see

```
Group/Show/group's section name/group name
```

instead of

```
Group/Show/1
```

How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the following route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "ShowRoute",
    "{controller}/show/{groupsection}/{groupname}/{classname}",
    new { controller = "class", action = "show", classname= UrlParameter.Optional },                
);
```

A few things to note:

1. You can choose any controller to be the default (e.g. controller="the_default")
2. You can declare all parameters as optional but you need to take care of null arg values in your code

You can then define your controller methods like this:

```
public ActionResult Show(string groupsection, string groupname, string classname) {    
}
```

And then have the following requests:

```
http://your_domain/class/group1-section5/group1/class-obedient

http://your_domain/group/group1-section5/group1/
```